# Sending an ordered Broadcast locally (within my process)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My requirement is this: My app needs to register for certain broadcasts. If my `Activity` is "showing"  when I receive the broadcast, then I update the UI; else, I show a `Notification`.

Commonsware has come up with an [elegant solution](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) for this; using ordered broadcasts. My problem is that I want to do all of this ***locally***, i.e., within my process. Unfortunately, [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) does not have a `sendOrderedBroadcast()` equivalent.

- Is this just an oversight in the `LocalBroadcastManager`?
- Or is it pointing to a best practice (something to the effect that sending ordered broadcast locally is a bad idea)? If so, why?
- Or is this plain unnecessary and can be achieved by alternate means?

Comment: Have you considered using `onUserLeaveHint()` and `onUserInteraction()` callacks in `Activity` class?

Comment: The docs say that these callbacks are specifically meant to help Activities decide when to cancel a notification. It looks like these are the methods where I need to register/unregister the receiver. I still don't see how the ordered broadcast can be avoided by using this approach.

Comment: you can start and stop a service in these callbacks for sending a notification..?

Comment: I see what you mean. I will try it out. Although I am still leaning towards an ordered broadcast solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own `LocalBroadcastManager` with ordered broadcast capability. The project is [shared at github](https://github.com/curioustechizen/curtech-android-utils/tree/master/ordered-local-bcmgr).

Although it serves my immediate purpose, it is still rough around the edges. It needs a few enhancements (for example, the `setResult*` and `getResult*` methods). Code contributions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this just an oversight in the LocalBroadcastManager?

Google does not have infinite engineering time.

> Or is it pointing to a best practice (something to the effect that sending ordered broadcast locally is a bad idea)?

I doubt it.

> Have you considered using onUserLeaveHint() and onUserInteraction() callacks in Activity class?

`onUserLeaveHint()` is insufficient here (e.g., does not cover the case where the user accepts an incoming phone call), and I fail to see how `onUserInteraction()` helps any.

Comment: I'm sorry - I did not intend to rant against Google when I mentioned "oversight" :). I guess what @userSeven7s meant was to stop the background service which raises the `Notification` in `onUserInteraction()` and start this service when user is about to leave `onUserLeaveHint()`. I interpret this to mean a finer grained control compared to doing the same in `onPause()`/`onStop()` or 'onResume()'/`onStart()` respectively. I don't have the complete picture yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare What is the correct way to secure "normally" sent broadcasts to the own application? (is it possible at all?)